# Spacy custom sentence segmentation on line break

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, data-science, spacy

I'm trying to split [this](https://uk.yahoo.com/finance/news/richard-branson-scrambles-save-flailing-133619510.html) document into paragraphs. Specifically, I would like to split the text whenever there is a line break (`<br>`)

This is the code I'm using but is not producing the results I hoped

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

def set_custom_boundaries(doc):
    for token in doc[:-1]:
        if token.text == "<br>":
            doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = True
    return doc

nlp.add_pipe(set_custom_boundaries, before="parser")
doc = nlp(text)
print([sent.text for sent in doc.sents])
```

A similar solution could be achieved by using [NLTK's TextTilingTokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/texttiling.html) but wanted to check whether there is anything similar within Spacy

Comment: https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching   I remember seeing something like [{"ORTH": "<"}, {"LOWER": "br"}, {"ORTH": ">"}],

Comment: How about simply replacing `<br>` with a dot before calling the spacy pipeline?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205475/sentence-segmentation-using-spacy

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, but the problem is that the default Tokenizer splits on '<' and '>',  hence the condition `token.text == "<br>"` is never true. I'd add space before and after `<br>`. E.g.

```
import spacy
from spacy.symbols import ORTH


def set_custom_boundaries(doc):
    for token in doc[:-1]:
        if token.text == "<br>":
            doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = True
    return doc

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
text = "the quick brown fox<br>jumps over the lazy dog"
text = text.replace('<br>', ' <br> ')
special_case = [{ORTH: "<br>"}]
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("<br>", special_case)

nlp.add_pipe(set_custom_boundaries, first=True)
doc = nlp(text)
print([sent.text for sent in doc.sents])
```

Also take a look at this PR, after it's merged to master, it'll no longer be necessary to wrap in spaces.

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/4259